# Is falling through trap doors worthwhile?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

Yesterday while playing legend of Grimrock, I fell through one of the many trap doors that litter the dungeon. Seeing how I've been very careful to avoid falling through trap doors up to that point, I expected this would lead to my prompt death, only to simply end up alive at the bottom (though the fall damage combined with some monsters took care of that).

Before dying, however, I saw that there was some exploration to do down there, perhaps even items? Generally, intentionally falling and hurting myself makes little sense, but perhaps there is much to be gained by jumping through trap doors?

If anyone has insight into this matter, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, falling into trap doors leads to many treasures.
You should still always consider saving first, after that just jump into every trapdoor you can find and enjoy the bonus loot.

Comment: yes, there are often secret areas that can only be obtained via falling.  And as far as I can tell so far, every hole has a teleport that will take you back to the previous level.

Answer (score 1):

There are several "hidden" areas that can only be accessed by falling through holes.

So I would actually try falling though all the holes (you can usually check once below which holes lead to new areas as the a hole 2 block to the right, will drop you down on the level to blocks to the right).